# How to validate Jenkins pipeline parameter inside bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins

In my Pipeline Jenkins job I have a Choice parameter called `BUILD_TYPE`:
[image]

I want to check which value is selected by user:

```
sh'''#!/bin/bash
     if [ "${params.BUILD_TYPE}" = "Debug" ]; then
         Debug = true
         Release = false
     else
         Debug = false
         Release = true
     fi
     '''
```

but got

```
line 2: ${params.BUILD_TYPE}: bad substitution
```

I also tried

```
[[ "${params.BUILD_TYPE}" == "Debug" ]];
```

with the same result...

What might be wrong with this code? What syntax should I use in Jenkins?

Comment: You should put the shell instructions in a script file rather than in-lining it. Though, I am pretty sure you could more appropriately code this into Groovy script that Jenkins will run natively instead.

Comment: @LéaGris I'm not really familiar with Groovy syntax.. I tried `script{if (${params.BUILD_TYPE}=="Debug") {Debug = true Release = false}  else {Debug = false Release = true}}` but that didn't work

Comment: @LéaGris should it be like `script{if (env.BUILD_TYPE=="Debug") {env.Debug = true env.Release = false}  else {env.Debug = false env.Release = true}}`?

Answer (score 0):

I worked mostly with bat command but from what I remember you can't use `${var}` between ''' (triple simple quote). To use it, you need to use """ (triple double quote). Just by changing this you should be able to get the value of `${params.BUILD_TYPE}` in your sh command.

EDIT:
Your whole sh script should be in """. So it should look like this in the end

```
sh"""#!/bin/bash
     if [ "${params.BUILD_TYPE}" = "Debug" ]; then
         Debug = true
         Release = false
     else
         Debug = false
         Release = true
     fi
     """
```

Comment: Tried `[ """${params.BUILD_TYPE}""" = "Debug" ]`. also didn't work. the same error...(

Comment: What about *bat command*? I don't really need to stick to bash. Just need an expected result

Comment: @DonnyFlaw then do it in Goovy which is natively handled by Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is wrong with this code:

1. Isn't the point of pipelines  to avoid writing shell code?
2. This is not valid shell code. For one, environment variable names cannot contain ".". It looks like a mish mash of shell and java or something. I believe Jenkins will pass parameters in plain variables like $BUILD_TYPE, but I haven't done much pipe lines so you'll have to check that.
3. In shell code you can't have space between the name and rvalue. It would have to be Debug=true
4. This shell code does nothing. It sets some variables then exits, so nothing is achieved. Variables set in the shell won't make their way anywhere else.

I think you need to back to first principles and read some books on this one.